# Canvas lms rest API export the data

Tags: ruby, api, canvas, canvas-lms

I need to export the data from canvas lms, i followed [Canvas API](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/) and create the token id. Now i can access the web api and got response 
here my problem was i create the token id for admin user and i need to get all courses (api/v1/courses/) but unfortunately enrolled courses only return. 
i need to do same for all assignment, quiz by date.

Under my knowledge for understanding canvas lms api document there is no way to get the data by created date and also not possible to get data without restriction.

Could you please guide me is it possible way to get all courses without restriction and also get data by created_date like once i send the timestamp it will return after created the data.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [List active courses in an account](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/accounts.html#method.accounts.courses_api) endpoint to get all of the courses. Once you have the course ids you can iterate over that to retrieve the rest of the data.

Comment: It may be that the user that your token belongs to doesn't have the correct permissions to get all of the courses.  Are you able to see all of the courses in the UI for the user that issued the token?

Comment: Yes, i create the token for admin